# Is it possible to execute an exe file from java inside a docker container

Tags: java, windows, docker, cmd

I have an app `application.exe`. I want to run it from java program. This is my method

```
public void runApp(JsonData json) throws Exception {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("my/dir/application.exe",
            json.getParam());
    Process process = pb.start();
    process.waitFor();
}
```

When I run my app as a spring boot, everything is fine. However when I run this app inside a docker container, I get an error `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "my/dir/application.exe": error=2, No such file or directory`. I guess that's because docker container doesn't have a windows command line support. My Dockerfile

```
From openjdk:8
copy ./target/converter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar converter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
CMD ["java","-jar","converter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

I tried adding cmd.exe into root folder, but it didn't work. What can I do to make my code working?

Comment: Its self explainatory, you have no `my/dir/application.exe` inside your docker container.

Comment: But I do have inside my project folder a my/dir and there application.exe. Isn't it sufficient? If not, could you please give me some advise what to do?

Comment: but it must be inside the docker container, and I dont see you copyuing it anywhere except jar file.

Comment: i added to my dockerfile `COPY ./my/dir/application.exe my/dir/application.exe`  Now I get a Nullpointer exception in another method that tries to access files created by my `application.exe` (exe should create a folder temp and load there some files from the web there). As it is exe, shouldn't I add to FROM something microsoft-ish?